# SQL Count amount of items in a few different groups

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Let's say I have the following data:

```
Food
----
Taco
Taco
Taco
Pasta
Pasta
Egg
```

And I want the following result:

```
Food  | Count
------|-------
Taco  |   3
Pasta |   2
Egg   |   1
```

How would I achieve this using SQL? I'm assuming I use count functions, but I only know how to count everything:

```
SELECT food, COUNT(food)
FROM menus
```

Comment: just add `GROUP BY food`

Comment: And remember- tables need primary keys

Answer (score 1):

If you group your data then aggregation functions like `count()` apply to each unique value in the group and not the complete result set

```
SELECT food, COUNT(*)
FROM menus 
group by food
```